# NCrunch gets stuck at 'NCrunch is initialising'

Tags: ncrunch

On an occasion, I found NCrunch was getting stuck at this step when 'NCrunch engine is initialising':

[image]

Clean/rebuilds and restarting Visual Studio did not resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue, I closed Visual Studio and navigated to the Visual Studio project folder in the file directory and located the hidden *.vs* folder and the '*_*NCrunch* _[projectName]*' folder and deleted those.

Then I cleaned and rebuilt the solution and NCrunch started functioning again.